# xcode Reading/writing dxf and dwg files

Tags: xcode, dwg, dxf

can anybody give me some directions as to how to read and write the DWG/DXF files.

what i want to achieve is that I want to create a drawing using Quaztcore.(which i can do). but i want to send this drawing  via a mail composer in a format which can be opened in auto cad.

Any documents, books, sites, code samples or any suggestions or are most welcomed.

In short, programmatically convert the drawing file into auto cad file.

Comment: Did you find your way to create and write on dxf file by using swift?

Answer (score 5):

[Here](http://usa.autodesk.com/adsk/servlet/item?siteID=123112&id=12272454&linkID=10809853) is a link to the official AutoCAD DXF reference.  I recommend looking at the R14 variety because it's simpler.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but this is not I am looking for. I want the xcode coding for reading and writing the drawing files.

Comment: Broken link. PDF now here: https://images.autodesk.com/adsk/files/autocad_2012_pdf_dxf-reference_enu.pdf